# Why was Abin Sur near planet Earth when he was attacked?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In the movie Green Lantern, why was Abin Sur near planet Earth so that he can escape to the nearest planet?

Comment: Earth was in his sector... and it was the closest planet with life on it....

Comment: Good, put your comment as answer so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abin_Sur#The_Prophecy) might be a better explanation.

Comment: @Thecafremo That's from the comics, not the film.

Comment: "escape to the nearest plant" - those Green Lanterns really are green eh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earth was in his sector... and it was the closest planet with life on it....

Comment: But any particular reason he happened to be 'closest' to earth at the time ?  After all, other planets with life in the sector, correct (his planet for sure) ?  Was he 'patrolling' this region for some reason ?

Comment: @Stan He was certainly patrolling, as he was checking in with home-base at the time; Beyond that, he was closest to Earth because there wouldn't be a movie otherwise...

Answer (score 3):

**Earth is one of the many planets in [Sector 2814](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Sector_2814) inhabited with life and visited by Green Lantern Abin Sur during his tenure as Green Lantern. As far as why he was attacked near Earth, historically, it was an accident he happened to be near Earth when he died and his ring chose Hal Jordan as his successor.**

- Having been a Lantern since the 1800s Earth time, he had made several trips to Earth and even interacted with Human heroes in the past.

#### Comic Apocrypha

Before the last reboot of the DC Universe, Earth and Sector 2814 had the dubious distinction of being a Multiversal focus point and is was protected by at least four Green Lanterns, [Hal Jordan](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_%28Hal_Jordan%29), [John Stewart](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/John_Stewart_%28New_Earth%29), [Guy Gardner](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Guy_Gardner_%28New_Earth%29), [Kyle Rayner](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_Rayner_%28New_Earth%29) and now [Simon Baz](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Simon_Baz_%28Prime_Earth%29).